# templateUrl runs before link funtion in AngularJS directive, why must I apply a $timeout

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I was wondering, in my directive I inherit data from a parent controller that I pass to my `templateURL` and I then use this data in an `ng-repeat`. Now in my directive is used in different views and depending on where I apply the directive we wish to show and hide various HTML elements in my template using `ng-if`

my template is declared like so

```
<div data-list-output="viewtype">
```

Where view type can be either products, customers or orders. My template looks like so:

```
<ul>
<li data-ng-repeat="data in dataArray track by $index"> 
    <!-- here we have some conditions depending on the contents of the 'data' objects we iterate -->
</li>
<ul>
```

Now the problem is in each parent controller the object that I use as 'dataArray' has a different name so I must amend this in my directive like so

```
.directive('listOutput', function () {
        'use strict';
         return {
            restrict: 'A',
            templateUrl: 'my-results-table.html',
            link: function (scope, element, attr) {

            if (attr.listOutput === 'products') {
                scope.dataArray = scope.products; // scope.products =[{}, ...]
            } else if (attr.listOutput === 'customers') {
                scope.dataArray = scope.customers;
            } else if (attr.listOutput === 'orders') {
                scope.dataArray = scope.orders;
            }
          };
});
```

The problem is that the directive loads the template before the link function executes, so the `ng-repeat` is empty (nothing is shown) and should I try to `console.log(scope.dataArray)` in the conditions above I get `undefined`. When I wrap a `$timeout` everything works and all is well, so my question is "why must I wrap the condition in a `$timeout` like so"?

```
$timeout(function() {
  if (attr.listOutput === 'products') {
   scope.dataArray = scope.products; // scope.products =[{}, ...]
  } else if (attr.listOutput === 'customers') {
   scope.dataArray = scope.customers;
  } else if (attr.listOutput === 'orders') {
   scope.dataArray = scope.orders;
  }
 });
```

Comment: don't understand your question, maybe more code could be helpful

Comment: why must I wrap the condition in a $timeout in the directive?

Comment: If `scope.dataArray` gives undefined then products, customers and orders don't exist at that point. Where do they come from?

Comment: They come from the parent controller

Comment: Can you show the code for that?

Comment: The content comes from services in the CTRL using $http / XHR - I assume that is the reason we have the delay!

Comment: Yea `$http` is asynchronous so your link function is running before the request completes. For solutions you could use `ng-if` to only create the directive once the request completes, or use `scope.$watch` in the link function

Comment: Or you could set the $scope.products on the controller to some initial value `$scope.products = []`. Then when the XHR completes do `angular.copy` wrapped in a `$timeout`